# connectiong c9 wordpress to mysql-workbench

Tags: wordpress, mysql-workbench, cloud9-ide

How can i connect my database in `MySQL` workbench with the WordPress blog on `Cloud 9`?
I have created a blog on the WordPress `workspace` on `Cloud 9`, and have separately connected `MySQL` workbench to a `MySQL` database.
I edited the `wp-config` file in WordPress and changed the `database name, username password and database host`. 
Now, how do i use this database for the word press blog? 
Kindly answer ASAP.

Comment: Does this help: https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/running-wordpress-on-cloud9 ? Although, can you explain your setup a bit more. Is your MySQL database running on Cloud9, or external?

Comment: it is external thats why i have connected it to mysql workbench. i want to know how to change the base url in mysql workbench.

Comment: In your wp-config.ini, changing this line: `define('DB_HOST', getenv('IP'));` to point to the external MySQL database doesn't work?

Comment: it is still not working. there is a blank page in the browser as an output.
unable to understand  the problem. @Mutahhir

Comment: Is your wordpress server running on 0.0.0.0:8080 on your workspace? Also, do you have any error logs regarding this?